# graphics magicks rotation 90 when bytes is passed from stdin and read from stdout

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

When I try to pass a jpeg which have exif rotation as 90 and try to resize my resize image gets corrupted. The fix for now is passing the image as a file and reading the output also as file. Currently I am reading and writing the bytes from stdin and stdout directly from my Java processBuilder.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs?

gm convert -limit threads 4 -limit Memory 512M -limit Map 1024M -limit Disk 1024M -size 2048x1458 - -flatten -sharpen 1.00x0.95 -rotate 90 -scale '2048x2048>' +profile !icm,* -interlace None -type TrueColor -quality 93 -sampling-factor 1x1 jpeg:-

UPDATE:
This has nothing to do with rotation. 
The problem is since the jpegs have some trailer in the end of the file.

.........
JPEG RST7
JPEG RST0
JPEG EOI
Samsung trailer (129 bytes at offset 0x1ba3ed):

gm identify gives below result

rotate_1_37658078940_605a46_o.jpg JPEG 2592x1944+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 1.7M 0.000u 0:01

gm identify: Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG (rotate_1_37658078940_605a46_o.jpg).

Comment: Does the corruption have *anything* to do with the rotation?

Comment: Yup. I got a pattern only in 270 and 90 deg rotation.

Comment: If you use ImageMagick, there is an -auto-orient command that tell the image to get he proper rotation from the EXIF orientation, correct that rotate. Then you can add further rotation. I do not know if graphicsMagick has some thing similar.

Comment: You know what there is -auto-orient and -orient command in gm and I tried both of them. The result are same as -rotation

Comment: Try removing the `-size 2048x1458`, the `-flatten`, the `-type truecolor` and `-interlace none` since they are likely superfluous. Then try removing all the limits leaving only `-threads 1` and see if that helps... just trying to debug.

Comment: Things worked when I replaced jpeg:- (which is jpeg in stdout) to actual file. But thats not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: I tried this command: ```gm convert -limit threads 1 - -resize 1024x1024> jpeg:-``` but still I didn't work. However, if I create a temp file things work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with Graphics Magick convert. The redirectError stream was set to true due to which the stderr was clubbed with stdout(bytes).